# manipulate data in a cell with Python (Openrefine)

Tags: python, pandas, openrefine

I need to edit all the 3000 phone numbers in a column so that the dialling code is in brackets. For example from:
 +49 089 / 514 6977 - 18
To:
+49 (089) 514 6977 - 18

Im guessing with Panda should be possible. Im using open refine?

Comment: `s[:4]+'('+s[4:7]+')'+s[7:]`

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
df['Column_Name'] = df['Column_Name'].apply(lambda x: x[:4]+'('+x[4:7]+')'+x[9:])
```

And if you have a single and double or even triple digit after plus, go with this:

```
df['Column_Name'] = df['Column_Name'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([part if i != 1 else '(' + part + ')' for i, part in enumerate(x.split()) if i != 2]))
```

And if some are properly written you can use:

```
df['Column_Name'] = df['Column_Name'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([part if i != 1 else '(' + part + ')' for i, part in enumerate(x.split()) if i != 2]) if '(' not in x else x)
```

Comment: apply should work, however since some countries have non 2 digit country code (+1 for US, +420 for Czech Republic) the approach with x[:4] won't work. I'd suggest regex

Comment: @VictorG. you are absolutely correct, so I made an edit for those cases :)

Comment: Hi Zipa, thanks for your response.  What if some of the numbers already had brackets on them? and do I just change the 'column_name' to the actual column name in openrefine?

Comment: Yes, you should change `'Column_name'` to your column, as for the  brackets see new edit.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Open Refine, you can try something like this :

```
value.replace(/(\d{3}) \//, "($1)").replace("/", "")
```

[image]

Comment: Ettore you genius! Is their a directory or something where I can look up functions like this for openrefine?

Comment: The [official documentation](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Documentation-For-Users) is probably the best place to start, especially the pages "Grel string functions" and "recipes". But this documentation is much less provided than that of Python of course. Note that Open Refine can also use Python/Jython if you are more comfortable in this language than with GREL.